# What is the DC and how much does it cost to repair a Sturdy Shield?

Tags: crafting, pathfinder-2e, shield

It is 4th level (Hardness 8, HP 64, and BT 32), and has taken 30 damage in the last encounter.

How many times do I have to roll what DC, and how much does it cost me?

I have found [Repair](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=42), but I still don't know the DC (it is not listed at the item), and it doesn't even mention the cost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Repair](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=42) activity says, in part -

> The GM sets the DC, but it’s usually about the same DC to Repair a given item as it is to Craft it in the first place.

[Crafting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=559) says -

> When a character Crafts an item, use the item’s level to determine the DC, applying the adjustments from Table 10–6 for the item’s rarity if it’s not common.  You might also apply the easy DC adjustment for an item the crafter has made before. Repairing an item usually uses the DC of the item’s level with no adjustments, though you might adjust the DC to be more difficult for an item of a higher level than the character can Craft.

The [Level-based DC](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=554) table lists the DC of 4th level as 19. This would be the default DC to repair the Sturdy Shield.

There is no cost involved to repair an item. However, you do need to have a Repair Kit available, which presumably provides any supplies required.

As listed in the Repair Activity,a success will restore 5 Hit Points to the item, plus an additional 5 per proficiency rank in Crafting (for a total of 10 HP for trained, 15 HP for expert, 20 HP for master, or 25 HP for legendary). A Critical success will double this, and a Critical Fail will cause more damage. Therefore, the number of attempts required to repair the shield will vary considerably based on the capability of the repairer. Assuming a Trained Crafter, at least 3 Successful repair attempts will be required (taking 10 minutes per attempt) to repair all 30 of the damage.

Comment: the Quick Repair skill feat can help significantly with that time cost.

Comment: Improvised Repair is even faster :) https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2132

Comment: @YogoZuno, it does not work on a Sturdy Shield